# Elasticsearch, Publishing on Private IP

Tags: elasticsearch

I set these lines in elasticsearch.yml, so Elasticsearch is visible from public network.

network.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1_ip","host2_ip" , ...]

However, when I look at the log file, I see these lines:

```
[INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [node-dtk6] publish_address {172.16.3.2:9300}, bound_addresses {[::]:9300}
[INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [node-dtk6] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks
```

Also, Kibana shows 172.16.3.2:9300 instead of the public IP. However, my node is visible from public network!

How can I force elasticsearch to publish on public IP instead of private IP?

Comment: what is your public IP?

Comment: your question is very unclear. only I know "network.host: 0.0.0.0" is wrong and it should be an IP (like your private IP).

Comment: Why is it ('0.0.0.0') wrong?

Comment: Do you run elasticsearch on docker?

Comment: I found the problem is because of the firewall which is put outside the OS! I found the problem using the `ip addr` command which showed the private IP instead of public IP.

Answer (score 0):

My problem raised because of a secondary firewall which is placed on my network's way.

I found the problem using the `ip addr` command which is showed me the private IP instead of public IP. However, Elasticsearch response the query since the firewall redirect the public IP into the elasticsearch.

When I disabled the firewall, Kibana showd the public IP and the published_ip in Elasticsearch log was changed to public IP.